# 'lock' datastore access while cron task running

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, cron

I have an application that I am planning to deploy on Google App Engine. Access to the datastore is through JPA. I also have several cron tasks that run throughout the day. My question is, is there a way that I can essentially prevent certain datastore entries from being accessed while the cron task is running?

Let's say the datastore entries for a particular table were Orders, and there was a cron task that is 'processing' these orders. I don't want the users to be able to modify the order while that task is running.

My first thought was to have all of the entities implement a simple interface called locked, and the cron task would set the lock value to true for all of the entitites that it was going to be processing, and then unlock them at the end, but that would require a ton of database updates each time the cron runs, and I'm sure there has to be a more efficient way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this transaction mechanism](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#Java_What_can_be_done_in_a_transaction). Transactions provide a guarantee that any changes required to individual entities will be synchronized and therefore prevent a potential race condition.

Or you can add "state" property in your order model. Whose values could be "processing", "pending", "delivered", etc. Then your cron can change it and your login read it to ensure that anyone will be able to modify it.